# To change directory inside a ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a new rails application and fire up the rails server for that application, everything from a ruby script.

My code look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
system "rails new my_app"
system "cd my_app"
system "rails server &"
```

However, when running "rails server &" the path is not in the my_app folder, but in the parent folder.

Is there a way to change directory inside a script so that i can run "rails server", "rake about" and "rake db:migrate" for that new application?

All work around tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the best answer is not the marked one. Keep reading to the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#method-c-chdir):

```
Dir.chdir "my_app"
```

Comment: Keep in mind this can have side-effects throughout the rest of your program.  See other answers to avoid potential bugs from this.

Comment: This is a bad answer. It solves the problem, but you can have a problem in code after it. Please consider to change "best answer" to another one (with more upvotes)

Comment: Worked well, but when the script is over, the shell is still in its initial directory. Any way to leave the script in that other directory we changed into?

Answer (score 396):

Don't listen to them, `Dir.chdir("dir")` will probably do the wrong thing. What you almost always want is to limit change to a particular context, without affecting the rest of the program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
system "rails new my_app"
Dir.chdir("my_app") do
  system "rails server &"
end
# back where we were, even with exception or whatever
```

Comment: Be very careful using a block in a threaded application such as one that uses sidekiq. Just and FYI :)

Comment: @jryancanty If I make a thread, and change directory like in this answer, what are the "side effects," if any? (I will not use sidekick, just `Thread` class)

Comment: I am also curious as to what the side effects are (from using either method). If you change the working directory, you can always change it back, right?

Comment: Don't know of any times you can't...just do ```original_directory = Dir::pwd```, then recall the variable later like so: ```Dir::chdir(original_directory)```

Answer (score 17):

system supports :chdir argument that allows you to specify its working directory:

```
system("echo Test; pwd", chdir: '/tmp')
```

outputs '/tmp'

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M002314) to change the working directory for a script.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
system 'rails new myapp && cd myapp && rails server &'
```

Comment: When the system command fails, it will be harder to diagnose what went wrong -- did the rails app fail, did the cd fail, or did rails server fail?

Answer (score 1):

The following lines have the same output:

```
puts Dir.chdir("/tmp") { IO.popen("ls -la") { |io| io.read } } 

puts IO.popen(["ls", "-la", "/tmp"]).read

puts IO.popen("ls -la /tmp").read

# drwxrwxrwt 25 root       root       16384 июля  23 01:17 .
# drwxr-xr-x 22 root       root        4096 июля  22 13:36 ..
# drwxrwxr-x 12 itsnikolay itsnikolay  4096 июля  19 17:14 app_template
# drwx------  2 itsnikolay itsnikolay  4096 июля  21 15:04 .com.google.Chrome.dThb8f
# drwx------  2 itsnikolay itsnikolay  4096 июля  18 20:55 .com.google.Chrome.FGDBGc
```

also you can run rails and create an application (this can be helpful in rspec tests and etc.):

```
IO.popen("cd /tmp/ && rails new test_app").read
```

and ever you can run a rails server ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Dir.chdir("[aString]")**