# Calling shell command to run C++ code from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

I have a compiled c++ file that I would like to run from within a temporary directory in ruby:

```
folder = Dir.mktmpdir
      begin
      puts folder
      File.open("#{folder}/input.xml", 'w') { |file| file.write(builder.to_xml) }

      ensure
      system '.././program'
      FileUtils.remove_entry folder
      end
```

The above code properly creates all the desired file/folder, but does not run the system call, and does not produce an error. I have tried the all of the varieties listed here: [Calling shell commands from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby) but cannot seem to get it to function. If I comment out the file deletion line and manually go and execute the command listed above, the program functions properly. Also, if I instead save the file to the same location as the ./program, the ./program works. What is preventing me from running the command from a sub-folder?

Comment: using `system` allows you to check it's return value, so if you did `puts system '.././program'` what does the console show?  True = 0 exit status, False = non-zero exist status, nil = execution failed.  Also you could try it in pry/irb without the need for puts.

Comment: The console has a blank line representing where the output should be printed

Comment: I don't think your path is right, I just tried using system from a variety of dir's and it's working.

Comment: That means it was nil, the file wasn't found most likely

Comment: The call to `system` does not run "from" any particular sub-folder, and I cannot see where you change directory? Are you expecting the command to be run with current directory equal to value of `folder`? You probably need to cd - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339883/to-change-directory-inside-a-ruby-script - also consider using full paths, and alter your C++ program to accept a path to the file it is processing rather than loading in the file from the current dir.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Or change the C++ program to accept the XML on the standard input and use [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) to talk to it.

Comment: @NeilSlater, the problem was not being in the correct folder, and was resolved using Dir.chdir, Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

maybe system finding a program has name `.././program`

try the backtick operator or %x function

```
puts `.././program`

puts %x{.././program}
```